# Saved bitmap in android is 3 bytes long when read

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have an activity to choose and save a profile picture. There is an image view and a button that starts the gallery activity for result awiting the user to choose an image. When the gallery is closed, the following code is executed:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO)) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap image = this.decodeAndScaleImage(selectedImage, 285);
            imgInsertPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

            this.imagePresent = true;
            this.saveMyProfilePicture(image);
            this.popImageView();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showToast(R.string.error_saving_picture);
        }
    }
}

private void saveMyProfilePicture(Bitmap picture) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(Globals.MY_PICTURE_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    picture.compress(Globals.MY_PICTURE_FORMAT, 90, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

    ByteArrayOutputStream rawOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    picture.compress(Globals.MY_PICTURE_FORMAT, 90, rawOutputStream);

    byte[] rawPictureData = rawOutputStream.toByteArray();
    rawOutputStream.close();

    byte[] base64PictureData = Base64.encode(rawPictureData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    rawPictureData = null;

    FileOutputStream base64OutputStream = openFileOutput(Globals.MY_PICTURE_B64_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    base64OutputStream.write(base64PictureData);
    base64OutputStream.close();
}
```

I debugged this code and verified that:
 - no exception is thrown;
 - the written files contain the exact amount of data (17kB for the jpg image, 24kB for the base64 version);
 - the produced bitmap is the one that I expect and is displayed correctly in the image view.

popImageView is only used to bump the image view on top of other views that were on the front before an image was chosen; and decodeAndScale method only works on bitmap data in memory and doesn't save anything.

However, when I try to reload the current picture when the activity starts, the image displayed is blank and the jpeg file conly contains 3 bytes:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (!imagePresent && pictureExists()) {
        File pictureFile = new File(getFilesDir(), Globals.MY_PICTURE_FILE_NAME);
        imgInsertPicture.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));
        popImageView();
        imagePresent = true;
    }
}
```

Here pictureExists checks that the file name is contained in the collection returned by listFiles(). pictureFile.exists() returns true, but as I said, it conly contains 3 bytes. I also tried using BitmapFactory.decodeX, but since the file is broken, it was useless.

I cannot understand why. I checked that the file was written entirely and then it disappears... 
When I was debugging on my Nexus S the code worked fine, but then I switched to a Nexus 5 and it broke.

Comment: If the file is being read correctly, and later found to be truncated, then something is overwriting your file.  One approach to debugging this would be to add "how big is it now" checks at various points in your program, or step with the debugger while doing frequent `ls -l` from adb shell to see if the file is still intact.  At some point the size will change, and you can narrow it down from there.

Comment: I've done this: the size is different only when read in the onStart method when  it is called for the first time.

Comment: So the size is wrong in onStart(), but the size is still right when viewed from adb shell?  Or is your read function mis-reading the length of the file?  Or are you saying that the act of launching the activity is truncating the file?  If you put a breakpoint at the onStart() method entry, is the file already truncated then?  How is the activity launched -- does whatever is launching it know about this file?  Where is the file stored?  What else has access to it?

Comment: Umh... now it works, but I haven't touched the code at all... Now the image size is correct. I am puzzled, I kept on working on the project leaving this activity behind waiting for an answer :S

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decoding the file to a bitmap using BitmapFactory?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Haven't tested the following code but can you please try:

```
File pictureFile = new File(getFilesDir(), Globals.MY_PICTURE_FILE_NAME);

Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));
imgInsertPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
popImageView();
imagePresent = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onActivityResult

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

 Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                           selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        selectedImagePath =filePath;
```

then use selectedImagePath as file path.

Hope it helps.